# After building the CouchDB source using build-couchdb, how do I get rake to recognize an Erlang file has changed, and rebuild it?

Tags: couchdb, rake

On Debian 6.0, I am able to build the CouchDB source with the instructions given at https://github.com/jhs/build-couchdb.

After making a minor change to couchdb/src/couchdb/couch_db_updater.erl, and rerunning rake, the changes are not rebuilt.

How is CouchDB rebuilt using build-couchdb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the new official Build CouchDB location is https://github.com/iriscouch/build-couchdb. You will find an updated version there.

You are right, Build CouchDB loves to wipe out your changes and build from scratch a lot!

I have instructions about how I work at https://github.com/iriscouch/browserid_couchdb. Look in the README in the "Development" section. Basically you check out build-couchdb and then a *different* checkout of the regular CouchDB code.

1. Use build-couchdb to compile Erlang, libicu, etc. etc.
2. Simply run `make dev` in the CouchDB checkout

Comment: Thanks. Able to compile single Erlang file using the method you described.  Copied the modified erl file to CouchDB install and change was able to be made.